# How to merge multiple objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JSON object array in javascript :

```
  [{ "AuthorName" : "Abc", "BookName" : "book-1" }]
  [{ "AuthorName" : "Abc", "BookName" : "book-2" }]
  [{ "AuthorName" : "Abc", "BookName" : "book-3" }]
  [{ "AuthorName" : "Abc", "BookName" : "book-4" }]
```

Now I want to create a single JSON object from the above JSON objects array. The newly created single JSON object contains 2 properties: `AuthorName` and `BooKName` array. I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
{ "AuthorName" : "Abc", "Book" : ['book-1', 'book-2', 'book-3', 'book-4'] }
```

Now my question is, how can I achive this efficiently and with writing minimum code in javascript?

Comment: None of this is JSON. It is all JavaScript, as would be the code to iterate and compact the data. That said, you should clarify what your existing data structure is. What you show in your first code block is neither JSON nor executable JS.

Comment: Why do you start with so many single-element arrays? It's quite wasteful.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `"JSON Object"`.  JSON is a *string representation* of data.  It just happens to be *similar* to JavaScript object syntax.

Comment: What does your starting object actually look like?  What have you tried?  A simple way is just to loop through and compare the `AuthorName`s.

Comment: Your first code block is four completely separate statements declaring four completely separate one-element *JavaScript* arrays. It is not JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = {};
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    if(obj[myArray[i].AuthorName] == null)
        obj[myArray[i].AuthorName] = [];
    obj[myArray[i].AuthorName].push(myArray[i].BookName)
}
```

Comment: This won't make an array in the format requested.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat - Seems to me he wants an object not an array, but is using a syntax where he's putting square brackets around everything.

Comment: I have no idea what he wants, but hopefully this pushes him in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully, this will help:

```
var bookSort = function (bookarray) {
    var i, 
        book,
        authorArray = [],
        il = bookarray.length,
        j,
        jl,
        authorInArray;
    for (i = 0; i < il; i++) {
        authorInArray= false;
        jl = authorArray.length;
        book = bookArray[i];
        for (j = 0; j < jl; j++) {
            if (book.AuthorName = authorArray[j].AuthorName) {
                authorInArray= true;
                authorArray[j].BookName.push(book.BookName);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!authorInArray) {
            authorArray.push({AuthorName: book.AuthorName, BookName: [book.BookName]});
        }
    }
    return authorArray;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need a function that combines multiple objects.

If you create a general purpose function that does this, you can reuse it. I would discourage you from creating a solution with things like `authorArray` etc hard coded into it.

Let's create a function that takes multiple objects and combines them. Let's keep it simple and assume the objects look like the ones from your question. In other words the objects to combine will simply be a flat list of name value pairs. The values will either be a string or an array of strings.

### [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/AqR4Z/)

```
// A function that combines multiple object.
//   The original objects are made of name value pairs where the values are strings.
// If - for a key - the values are the same, the value is kept
// If - for a kye - the values are different, and array is created and the values pushed to it
//   after this all new values are added to the array if not already there.
var combineObjects = function() {

                 // see how many object are to be combined
    var length = arguments.length,
        i,
        // Create a new empty object that will be returned
        newObject = {},
        objectIn,
        prop,
        temp,
        ii,
        alreadyExists;

    // Go through all passed in object... combinging them
    for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {

        objectIn = arguments[i];

        for (prop in objectIn) {
            if (objectIn.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

                // Check if the prop exisits
                if (newObject[prop]) {

                     // Check if the prop is a single or multiple (array)
                    if (Object.prototype.toString.call( newObject[prop] ) === '[object Array]') {
                        // Multiple

                        // Check if element is in array
                        alreadyExists = false;
                        for (ii = 0; ii < newObject[prop].length; ++ii) {
                            if (newObject[prop][ii] === objectIn[prop]) {
                                alreadyExists = true;
                                break;                                    
                            }
                        }

                        if (! alreadyExists) {
                            newObject[prop].push(objectIn[prop]);
                        }

                    } else {
                        // Single   
                        if (newObject[prop] !== objectIn[prop]) {
                            temp = newObject[prop];
                            newObject[prop] = [temp, objectIn[prop]];                               
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    newObject[prop] = objectIn[prop];
                }
            }
        }                
    }  

    // Alert for testing
    alert(JSON.stringify(newObject));

    return newObject;        
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are after. Maybe this will work for you:

```
var books = [ 
  [{ "AuthorName" : "Abc", "BookName" : "book-1" }],
  [{ "AuthorName" : "Abc", "BookName" : "book-2" }],
  [{ "AuthorName" : "Abc", "BookName" : "book-3" }],
  [{ "AuthorName" : "Abc", "BookName" : "book-4" }]
];    

// First book in the array
var first = books[0][0];

// Add BookName property to the first book object (BookNames would be a better name)
first.BookName = books.map(function(book, n) {
  return book[0].BookName;
});

/*
  Or, use jQuery.map if you got a older browser that don't support the Array.map function
  $.map(books, function(book, n) {
     return book[0].BookName;
  });
 */

// first is now:
{ AuthorName : "Abc", BookName : ['book-1', 'book-2', 'book-3', 'book-4'] }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like those are just four seperate arrays containing objects.

If you put those four seperate arrays inside another array so they can be iterated, like so:

```
var a = [
        [{ AuthorName : 'Abc', BookName : 'book-1'}],
        [{ AuthorName : 'Abc', BookName : 'book-2'}],
        [{ AuthorName : 'Abc', BookName : 'book-3'}],
        [{ AuthorName : 'Abc', BookName : 'book-4'}]
        ];
```

I'd just do:

```
var new_array = [],
    temp_obj = {};

$.each(a, function(i,e) {
    var author = e[0].AuthorName,
        book   = e[0].BookName;
    temp_obj[author] ? temp_obj[author].push(book) : temp_obj[author] = [book];
});

$.each(temp_obj, function(author,books) {
    var obj = {AuthorName: author, BookName : books};
    new_array.push(obj);
});

//new_array is now = [{ AuthorName : 'Abc', BookName : ['book-1', 'book-2', 'book-3', 'book-4'] }]
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6UG4c/1/)

and it would sort out more authors and books etc. aswell ?

[**PROOF**](http://jsfiddle.net/6UG4c/2/)